# flash of unstyle content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-cycle2

I have an following issue with cycle2, all my images display briefly when the page loads, there is possible solution http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/faq.html
but it didn't help with stop flashing so the problem seems to be different:

For Cycle the possible solution is: hide all but your first slideshow image using CSS. For example:

```
#slideshow img { display: none }
#slideshow img.first { display: block }
```

...

```
 <div id="slideshow">
    <img src="image1.jpg" width="200" height="200" class="first" />
    <img src="image2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="image3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
 </div>
```

My initial question was, how to apply these css two lines to cycle2 code but after testing recommendation it didn't help so looking for solution how to prevent flashing.

Here is how cycle2 code looks like in my inc/top.inc.php file:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://example.com/js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

 <div class="fl_left logo_add">
 <div class="fl_left cycle-slideshow"
     data-cycle-slides=">a"
     data-cycle-timeout="15000"
     data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
     data-cycle-speed="500"
     >
     <a title="<?=$lang[1159]?>" href="<?=$h?>"><img src="<?=$im?>logo.jpg" > </a>
     <a title="<?=$lang[1159]?>" href="<?=$h?>p9.html"><img src="<?=$im?>logo.jpg" > </a>
 </div>
```

Below is link to files:

[jquery.cycle2.min.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VuJStpyJUw6WQPThkqWyGkgLJsklCQ9r/view?usp=sharing)

[top.inc.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_KGMUewVze-gdQow3pauwHdUduw29UM8)

slideshow codes start from --LOGO ADD-- in top.inc.php

thanks, S

Comment: So your question is simply how to include a custom CSS file?

Comment: The `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash and never has.

Comment: I removed the slash, still the same issue. As I mentioned in last message, the problem is seem different than just hiding images. I posted files.

Comment: I deleted my answer for now, since it might not be the best solution to your problem. To know what is, we need a _working_ code snippet, _reproducing_ the issue you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. Basically what was happening to me anyway was even if I was doing what cycle told me to do which was

```
.slide { display: none; }
.slide:first-of-type { display: block; }
```

was not working.  What I found was as soon as the jQuery kicked in it added the absolute positioning to the slides before it was making a duplicate of the first to be the `.cycle-sentinel` which then becomes a static image that gives the window its dimensions. What worked for me was

```
.slide { display: none; }
.slide:first-of-type { display: block; position: static !important;}
```

This way the first slide stays static and in place until `.cycle-sentinel` is created at which time that becomes first of type and its supposed to be static anyway.  Hope that helps in some way.